# Existe alguma Api de transcrição de áudio que possa ser usada em PHP, biblioteca em C ou em Java?

Tags: áudio, transcrição-de-áudio, asr

Estou em busca de uma api que consiga ao receber o áudio, tente reconhecer o texto. Alguém conhece alguma api opensource para isso? O contrário (receber um texto e gerar um áudio tem várias). A intenção é instalar no servidor local (linux) e usar junto com o PHP. Se existe qual seria?

Objetivo inicial é em empregar uma ferramenta anti-captcha, em geral hoje tem muitos sites que além de ter a imagem tem a opção de áudio, uma vez tendo o áudio, posso enviar para uma api dessa e submeter o captcha, ficando assim mais fácil de consumir serviços, como consulta e validação de CPF, CNPJ e etc...

Hoje eu consigo usar o CURL para capturar normalmente os HTML, fazer o anti-captcha para imagens esbarra em muitas questões onde nem sempre o algoritmo é eficiente para quebrar o captcha e ainda a a necessidade de desenvolver algoritmos para imagens diferentes.

Nas pesquisas que fiz encontrei muita coisa para gerar áudio a partir de texto, mas o contrário gerar texto a partir de áudio eu somente encontrei em aplicações fechadas onde eu precisaria utilizar a aplicação juntamente com tecla de atalho para resolver a questão. Como vai ficar rodando em um servidor web não achei uma boa solução.

Encontrei o GoogleSpeech, cai na página http://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/reconhecimento-de-voz-no-linux-utilizando-google-speech-api-google2ubuntu/, contudo, não cheguei a implementar, pois quando comecei a ler vi que ia funcionar pela tecla de atalho e pelo microfone. Isso sem dúvida seria uma das implementações possíveis no pior dos casos e se não tivesse uma forma mais fácil de usar. "quando você quiser acionar o sistema de reconhecimento de voz Google2Ubuntu, pressione o atalho de teclado que você configurou. Ao pressionar o atalho de teclado..."

Comment: Já viu se o GoogleSpeech não tem alguma extensão que faça isso? Ele funciona assim: http://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/reconhecimento-de-voz-no-linux-utilizando-google-speech-api-google2ubuntu/

Comment: A pessoa que votou para fechar poderia explicar o motivo? creio que é uma pergunta objetiva com uma resposta certa ou errada dentro do escopo SO-pt

Comment: O pessoal leva muito a ferro e a fogo o que manda a Central de Ajuda. Experimenta editar sua pergunta com mais informações, como o propósito da questão, o que já tentou...

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, nas pesquisas que fiz encontrei muita coisa para gerar áudio a partir de texto, mas o contrário gerar texto a partir de áudio eu somente encontrei em aplicações fechadas onde eu precisaria utilizar a aplicação juntamente com tecla de atalho para resolver a questão. Como vai ficar rodando em um servidor web não achei uma boa solução. E resolvei postar a pergunta aqui, para ver se o pessoal auxiliava, dando uma direção como o erderwander fez em sua resposta.

Comment: @Dante cheguei a ver, cai exatamente nessa página, contudo, não cheguei a implementar, pois quando comecei a ler vi que ia funcionar pela tecla de atalho e pelo microfone. Isso sem dúvida seria uma das implementações possíveis no pior dos casos e se não tivesse uma forma mais fácil de usar. "quando você quiser acionar o sistema de reconhecimento de voz Google2Ubuntu, pressione o atalho de teclado que você configurou. Ao pressionar o atalho de teclado...", contudo, há como usar via api do google, mas essa alternativa eu não conhecia.

Comment: @RodrigoBorth, quanto a de fechar o tópico aqui já é normal, algusn esperam que para ser uma pergunta de programação tem que ter trecho de código, só que nem sempre é o caso, as vezes é questão conceitual, mas vai da interpretação de cada um votar por fechar, algumas vezes perde-se mais tempo e esforço debatendo que com base em determinando de ponto de vista a questão está fora de escopo, do que tentar dar uma solução e deixar algo útil não só para quem fez a pergunta, mas para outros internautas. Até porque fechar só impede novas respostas, não se estressa com essas coisas.

Comment: Esta pegunta [está sendo discutida no Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1781/por-que-fechar-uma-pergunta-sobre-api-de-transcri%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-voz). . . . PS: Sileno, em vez de escrever tanta coisa aqui nos comentários, seria melhor editar a pergunta...

Comment: @brasofilo A pergunta foi editada, em geral costumo primeiro responder o comentário e depois editar a pergunta para tornar mais completa ou fácil de entender, poderá observar que já existem algumas edições nessa pergunta, contudo (não foi o caso dessa pergunta) tem comentários que não acho que cabem edições nesse caso não edito, mas acredito que quem gastou um tempo deixando o comentário, merece no minimo uma resposta, por esse motivo deixo tantos comentários.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você esta procurando por ASR (automatic speech recognition).

Open source é bem complicado de encontrar, estes algoritmos possuem um apelo comercial muito grande, tem alguns projetos bem antigos e eu acho que só suportam transcrição em inglês:

[Sphinx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/)

[freespeech](http://freespeech.sourceforge.net/FreeSpeech/html/)

Eu já testei o [verbio](http://www.verbio.com/br/) não é opensource, mas dá para instalar um demo dele e deixar rodando em modo evaluation tem suporte a lingua Portuguesa-BR.

Eu não pensaria duas vezes em utilizar o googlespeech, com a ajuda do `curl` você deve montar o cabeçalho adequado enviar o arquivo de áudio para o google e pegar a transcrição, primeiro você deve converter o arquivo de áudio para o formato flac e fazer resample para 8000hz, apos estes procedimentos é só enviar o arquivo para o google, em php você vai fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
$file_to_upload = array('myfile'=>'@'.$filename.'.flac');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=pt-BR&key=___my_api_key___");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=8000"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file_to_upload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
```

Eu faço  isso com python e funciona que é uma beleza :-)

Comment: Sua resposta está excelente, vou tentar isso, tinha feito algumas tentativas, mas as aplicações que encontrei, tinham que usar a interface gráficas delas. Não tentei o google, estava usando ele apenas para criar áudio a partir de textos.

Comment: Bacana, é só fazer acesso a API do googlespeech usando curl, eu não pesquisei, mas você vai achar códigos em php prontos que fazem exatamente isso, ahh só pra enriquecer, criar audio a partir de textos é chamado de TTS (Text To Speech)

Comment: Esse link também tem informações bem interessantes: http://stt.getflourish.com/

Comment: sim, ele explica como pegar a key para a segunda versão do googlespeech API(atual), infelizmente me parece que é permitido apenas 50 requisições diárias por chave gerada, até onde sei agora é permitido envio de arquivos .wav em 16 bits, ou seja não precisa mais converter para .flac

Comment: da uma olhada aqui (https://github.com/gillesdemey/google-speech-v2) tem exemplos de como enviar o audio via linha de comando no linux e pegar o retorno só usando curl

Comment: Até que conversão usando o sox não é muito problemático, mas é bom, pois é código e dependência a menos.

Comment: Legal, eu usei esse: Audacity durante um tempo, na época eu estava tentando fazer um conversor para compactar o áudio no formato g729, deu alguns problemas, que não me recordo quais eram e no fim outro projeto de mais prioridade ocupou o lugar da conversão e projeto do g729 nunca mais foi retomado.

Answer (score 0):

A AT&T tem uma API para Speech 2 Text aqui:https://developer.att.com/apis/speech/docs

Para usá-la você precisa se inscrever como developer, criar uma app e estabelecer uma gramática. Utilize o *speech to text custom*.

Comment: Ivo, podes explicar um pouco mais como essa API funciona e talvez [edit] a resposta com um exemplo ou dois?